# XPath - Test attribute value and text value

Tags: xml, parsing, xpath, xml-parsing

I am trying to write an Xpath condition that returns the element if its attribute and value are correct, otherwise return null.

Here is my xml

```
<record>
  <field name="uid">ABC70019469</field>
  <field name="effectiveDate">10 May 2014 00:00:00 BST</field>
  <field name="expiryDate">09 May 2015 23:59:59 BST</field>
  <field name="price">48.49</field>
  <field name="cancelled">{cancelled}</field>
  <field name="addonSection.effectiveStartTime">09 May 2014 09:04:29 BST</field>
  <field name="addonSection.effectiveEndTime">31 December 9999 23:59:59 GMT</field>
  <field name="addonSection.brand">BIT</field>
  <field name="addonSection.product">ProPlus</field>
<record>
```

I want to check if there is a field element with @name="addonSection.product" and value == ProPlus.

I have tried to use the following XPath, but it returns null every time.

```
//field[@name = 'addonSection.product']/[text()='ProPlus']
```

Any comments welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `/` between the conditions. Join your checks with an `and`:

```
//field[@name='addonSection.product' and text()='ProPlus']
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint input.xml --xpath "//field[@name='addonSection.product' and text()='ProPlus']"
<field name="addonSection.product">ProPlus</field>
```

Comment: thanks, just realised i was missing a capital letter from my actual code as well. facepalm. Thanks v much